# How can I override or alter a module's help text?

Tags: 8

I am trying to override or alter Layout Builder's default help text. Is is possible to do this? If so, how?

I have added some help text in a hook_help() function in a custom module but I can only get it to add to Layout Builder's help text. I can't find a way to override the default text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't recall doing exactly this, but I think you can use a [`hook_module_implements_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Extension%21module.api.php/function/hook_module_implements_alter) for this:

```
function MYMODULE_module_implements_alter(&$implementations, $hook) {
  if ($hook === 'help') {
    unset($implementations['layout_builder']);
  }
}
```

This should disable `layout_builder_help()`, and then just yours will run.  A `hook_help_alter()` would be nice, but I don't recall ever seeing an issue for it.

Comment: Thank you! I had the hook_module_implements_alter part working but I couldn't figure out how to remove the existing layout builder help. This works!